# Setting variables to C arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How does one set a variable to equal and array that got passed into a function. Lets say the function gets passed in the array (int* array_x). If I wanted to set that array to a variable x, wouldn't it be 
int x[] = array_x;

Doing this gives me an error and googling around I haven't been able to find an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just reference array_x in your function's code?

Comment: No. `array_x` is a `int*`, a pointer. Pointers and arrays are not the same thing. You are wildly guessing: which C++ book are you reading to learn the language?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The question is about C, not C++ (but they're very similar in this area).

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oops, I meant C book :) (habit)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays aren't assignable in C. But you can make copies using `memcpy()`.

E.g.:

```
void f(int* a, size_t element_count)
{
  size_t array_size = element_count * sizeof(int);
  int* b = malloc(array_size);
  memcpy(b, a, array_size);
}
```